# Ubuntu catastrophe after upgrading to Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: update-manager, 13.04, restore

I was eager to try the new Ubuntu 13.04 released today so I updated though the update-manager, sadly it becaume such a catastrophe. After rebooting the screen went black without me letting switch to a tty or anything.

I tried to switch from lightdm to gdm due to some related issues I read without any luck. 
I also tried booting with Linux 3.5 kernel and well, it boots succesfully, but there are a ton of bugs. The system font is messed up, gnome does not work properly, almost every app force closes, Ubuntu errors pops out every now and then prompting me to report them, old problems that were already solved are now back although the solution I coded is still there...

I guess it would take me more time to solve every bug than to make a new clean installation of Ubuntu.

Prior to that I could make a backup of my files. What method would be the best for that?

And then to the installing part. I guess the easiest way would be to boot from a USB/DVD, the bad part is that my laptop does not have a DVD drive and currently I don't have a big enought USB. Is it possible to mount the Ubuntu .iso from Ubuntu itself and restore the system? Or maybe an alternative solution...

A friend told me he could lend me a big enough USB so I could do the USB installation but if there is a solution that does not involve all my applications/configurations/files lost it would be perfect.

Lastly, should I install 12.10 or 13.04? I believe the problems came due to the update though update-manager so a clean installation should not cause any troueble, should it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried opening a terminal and using?

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

to see if that fixes itself??

Here is a link that may help too if it is a broken package issue of some sort causing the errors http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=947124

Good luck.  You may need to borrow your friends USB and do a clean install.

Comment: Yes, I did. The system is really messed up, there are more bugs that normal behavior and the kernel not booting seems like serious issues I won't be able to solve. I guess I'll go for a clean install.